# How to check if currently logged-in user is Azure Active Directory B2C "Global Administrator"? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure-active-directory

I would like only Users whose Directory Role is "Global Administrator" in my Azure Active Directory B2C tenant to be able to have access to a controller. Therefore, before the controller class is instantiated/run, I would like to perform a check similar to the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Global Administrator")]
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{
    .... controller class ....
}
```

I understand that in order to call the "Authorize" command above, I need to enable the Role Manager to sync with Azure Active Directory B2C, like so in Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

However, whenever the UserProfileController is created, then I get this error message:

> "Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user
>   name in the current Windows Identity."

And, in fact, I have confirmed that the following two items are unequal because userIdentityName gives the username of the Azure Active Directory B2C user currently logged into the web application, but windowsIdentityNames gives the username of me currently logged into my laptop:

```
string userIdentityName = User.Identity.Name;
string windowsIdentityName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

This tells me that using the "Authorize" command above the UserProfileController is the wrong way to check if the currently logged in user is a "Global Administrator".

Thus my questions are:

1. How can I check that the currently logged in user is a "Global Administrator" and prevent them from using UserProfileController if they are not?
2. Should I disable the RoleManager because it is impossible to use in this scenario?
3. Is there a way to check if the currently logged in user is a "Global Administrator" within the .cshtml also? I would like to display a button only for global admins.

======================================================

Edited to add the code for Startup.Auth.cs class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    private static string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
    private static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;
    public static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;

    public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
    {
        return graphClient;
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                   {
                       var code = context.Code;
                       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                       string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                       TokenCache userTokenCache = new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID);

                       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, userTokenCache);
                       AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                           code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                       string token = result.AccessToken;

                       try
                       {
                           graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                               new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                                   (requestMessage) =>
                                   {
                                       requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

                                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                                   }));
                       }
                       catch (Exception e)
                       {
                           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to create graph client: " + e.Message);
                       }

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**============ UPDATE ============**

This answer is very complete and answered this question: I found the answer to this question to be very helpful:
[Use AuthorizationAttribute to check user's roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531433/authorizeroles-admin-infinite-loop-asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-direct)

Comment: First you say Active Directory, then you say **Azure** Active Directory. Which one is it? They are two completely different products regarding to authentication APIs

Comment: Thanks. I have clarified that I am using Azure Active Directory B2C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question solved my problem.

[`[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` Infinite loop ASP.NET MVC and Azure Active Directory B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531433/authorizeroles-admin-infinite-loop-asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-direct)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using APIs that were created for Active Directory and attempting to consume Azure Active Directory. Azure Active Directory does not work, at all, with the built-in Membership providers.

The way your scenario is supported is through OAuth 2.0 / OpenId Connect. Read up "[Developing ASP.NET Apps with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)" for the basics of working with Azure AD in ASP.NET applications.
Since the most relevant part of the code is omitted, this is what your Startup.Auth file would look like:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
    });
```

The exact configuration you use will vary depending on whether you need access to other Azure APIs using the user's credentials, so be sure to check the manuals for your required cases.

Just remember this:

- authentication-mode: Windows => Active Directory
- OAuth 2.0 / OpenId Connect => Azure Active Directory

As soon as you got the configuration right, you will be able to use `[Authorize(Roles = "Global Administrator")]` without any problem.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped when you clarified the authentication protocols for AD vs Azure AD. I have edited the original question to include the code for Startup.Auth.cs, which includes your suggestion. However, I am still getting the same error: "Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity." I have taken a look at the documentation link provided (awesome, thank you!) and definitely need to keep looking, but can you point more specifically to what configuration I am still missing?

Comment: @Emilia Glad that helped. Did you remove the web.config sections? I find it likely that there's some provider still on and it's taking precedence over the authentication being set up by OWIN. That said, you might find it easier to create a new MVC project with Domain Accounts and copy over the relevant parts from the template

Comment: Also, if you have any suggestions for a better way for me to pass the graphClient object to other Controller classes, I would be happy to hear them. It seems cumbersome to have the graphClient object reside in the Startup class and to have a getter method named GetGraphServiceClient() because the Controller class could receive a null graphClient or a graphClient with a expired or close-to-expiring token. Thank you so much!

Comment: Camilo, are you saying that the roleManager should be disabled? If I remove the entire snippet from Web.config, then login hangs. However, if I still keep <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>, then I get the same error. I can definitely keep it as an option to create a new MVC project, but I know it will take a lot of work.

Comment: @Emilia I'd keep it as `enabled="false"` or remove it completely, same as with `authentication-mode="windows"`. That (Membership) does not work well with OWIN. I'd need to see that login, because it won't work OOB with Azure, most likely

Comment: alright, I removed both of them. Here is the login, following the formatting from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code). Does this provide any clues? : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_mode=form_post
&response_type=code+id_token
&scope=openid+profile
&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties{randomly_generated_id}
&nonce={randomly_generated_id}
&x-client-SKU=ID_NET
&x-client-ver=1.0.40306.1554`

Comment: @Emilia I don't remember exactly but that seems to be alright. You say you cannot login with that? Did you try with a new project? I recommended that because it's normally the fastest

Comment: I only can't login with that if I include the code `[Authorize(Roles = "Global Administrator")]` above the class declaration. If I delete this code, then logging in is fine. OK, I'll look into other projects. Thanks.