# Azure AD / ASP.net MVC application redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a ASP.net MVC project hosted in Azure and with Azure AD authentication

Everything works fine when I publish my project, but after a while when trying to login again, I get the famous login loop.

If I restart the app service, everything works fine for a while again...

I have read many posts and blogs regarding this subject and I think I have tried evertything.

- Reply url and keys are correct both in Azure and web.config
- Applicaton is forced to https
- I have tryed the katana cookiesaver fix.
- Reply url other than root

Other suggestions?

Comment: This one can be hard. Fundamentally it comes down to your authentication layer rejecting the request when it gets sent back to your app. Are you requiring authentication globally? I found that once that caused auth to be required before the OWIN middleware had a chance to run.

Comment: Maybe you could refer these solutions:1 Choose correct permissions(https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-Explorer/issues/1 ) 2.Define a custom authorize attribute(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531433/authorizeroles-admin-infinite-loop-asp-net-mvc-and-azure-active-direct).

Comment: I noticed this happened on a browser. When I opened the app in an incognito windows it worked... I eventually cleared cookies in the first browser and it started working.... still can't explain why unfortunately, but try and clear all cookies

Comment: @Rodney You can't really require users to do that though :)

Comment: Absolutely agree... I have noticed several odd issues with the Microsoft login and don't believe it is on the code-side. I think it is on their side (even when I try and log in to my own MS account and MS properties it's often a very bad user flow)

Comment: In my case it was an extra "/" at the end of the Reply URL configured in the App Registration on Azure AD which caused the loop.